# Lodash - use meanBy with multiple properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, mean

I have this array :

```
arr = [{a:1, b:2},
       {a:3, b:6}]
```

Using lodash, I want to get the mean of this array, like this:

```
{a:2, b:4}
```

For only one property I can use `_.meanBy(arr, 'a')`. Is there a similar syntax to get the mean for more than 1 property at the same time? Something that would look like `_.mean(arr, ['a', 'b'])`

It would be nicer than using `meanBy` twice as I suppose that there would only be one loop over the array...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`lodash#mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith) wrapped in a [`lodash#spread`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#spread) to treat the entire array as arguments. Use [`lodash#concat`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#concat) to provide the arguments together with the [`lodash#add`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#add) callback. Note that using an empty object as first argument makes sure that the items in the array aren't mutated.

```
var result = _.spread(_.mergeWith)(_.concat({}, arr, function(a,b) {
  return _.add(a, (b || 0) / arr.length);
}));
```

```js
var arr = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  },
  {
    a: 3,
    b: 6
  }
];

var result = _.spread(_.mergeWith)(_.concat({}, arr, function(a,b) {
  return _.add(a, (b || 0) / arr.length);
}));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: He needs the average of the number. Replace `_.add` with `function(a, b) {
  return (a || 0) + (b || 0) / arr.length;
}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array#reduce with Array#forEach to get an object of averages.

```js
var arr = [{a:1, b:2}, {a:3, b:6}];

var result = arr.reduce(function(mean, obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    mean[key] = (mean[key] || 0) + obj[key] / arr.length;
  });

  return mean;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```